# Installing Redmine on CentOS 5 - bundler problems?

Tags: ruby, rake, centos, bundler, redmine

I've hit a wall with my Redmine installation on CentOS.

```
[mryan@documents ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/mryan/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
[mryan@documents ~]$ sudo bundle show rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.3
[mryan@documents ~]$ sudo bundle exec rake generate_session_store
bundler: command not found: rake
Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
```

Any help very much appreciated.

mryan321

Answer (score 0):

Last I saw, Redmine didn't use Bundler so you will need to create a Gemfile for it and set up Bundler yourself. ChiliProject (a fork of Redmine) uses Bundler, you might be able to use that Gemfile instead

https://github.com/chiliproject/chiliproject/blob/unstable/Gemfile

Comment: If you're planning on running Redmine through Apache2/Passenger, you will in fact need bundler.